# decode mpeg2-ts frame from socket to RGB buffer

Tags: qt, ffmpeg, libavcodec, mpeg2-ts, libavformat

I'm trying to make a program that record my phone screen on my PC.
For that I made a simple client/server socket TCP. My Android phone records the screen and encapsulates an H.264/AAC data in MPEG2/TS and send it over socket continuously.

PC side, I'm using QT, I receive the stream on this function :

```
void Server::processBinaryMessage() {
    QTcpSocket *pClient = qobject_cast<QTcpSocket *>(sender());
    QByteArray byteArrayReceived = pClient->readAll();

    QFile f("record.ts");
    if (f.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append)) {
      f.write(byteArrayReceived);
      f.close();
    }
}
```

I wrote each QbyteArray to File to see if it's correct and played with VLC, it works good.
But I would like to decode those frames from memory using avformat.

I'm on QT 5.12.1 with msvc2017_64 compiler.

Thanks for help.

Comment: The answer is use the libav* from the ffmpeg project, And I can help you by posting some code. But as it stand, this question is too broad to answer, because reading from memory in libavformat is one problem, decoding video via libavformat/libavcode is a different problem. Converting that it RGB is a third problem, and rendering those RGB frames to an openGL surface is a fourth problem. Start with this https://github.com/leandromoreira/ffmpeg-libav-tutorial (read the whole thing) then ask clarifying questions on stackoverflow,.

Comment: Hello szatmary, thank you for your help I was able to integrate avformat to my project. I edited my question to be more clear about what I'm trying to do. My question is about reading from memory and pass it to avformat. Thanks for help